# Can you add an accented characters to the querty keyboard on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I'm looking to add another layer to the querty keyboard on the iPad so I can get accented characters.  Can I do that?

Comment: You mean hold the letters for a while?

Answer (score 7):

An even simpler way to access the most commonly accented characters is to hold down that letter and you are given options.

To see what I mean, just click and hold on the letter "o" and you'll be given a lot of choices.

The standard keyboard on a USA iPad will have accented characters for e, y, u, i, o, a, s, z, c and n.

Comment: Gee – I had no idea. I'll leave my answer up anyhow, as it could be useful too. But this is clearly the right answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do that is to add more keyboards. If you have several keyboards active, you can cycle through them using the globe key to the left of the space bar. To add more keyboards, go to Settings → General → Keyboard → International Keyboards. Pick a national keyboard that has the accented letters you want.

Comment: bonus: the spell checker will also spell check in that language. very useful!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not modify the keyboard layout itself without jail breaking the OS. The other answers do list the existing features for accessing these characters, but I have written an [article](http://www.lindipendente.eu/wp/en/2012/02/15/ipad-unfriendly-keyboard/) summarizing why having alternate keys on iOS isn't equivalent to keyboards with dedicated single key presses for commonly used keys.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thank you :)